# Plotting cities on a state map using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot certain cities in California on a state map. I've only managed to plot them on a Map of North America, not just California. Below is my code. How can I adjust it to show only California?

```
!pip install geopandas
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Latitude': [39.8938333, 40.363, 35.7758333, 33.8313333, 40.2705],
    'Longitude': [-123.4245, -124.2553333, -121.3043333, -118.2636667, -124.3813333]
})

df["Coordinates"] = list(zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
df.head()

df["Coordinates"] = df["Coordinates"].apply(Point)
df.head()

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="Coordinates")
gdf.head()

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world = world.set_index("iso_a3")

world.head()

world.geometry.name

fig, gax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

world.query("continent == 'North America'").plot(ax = gax, edgecolor='black', color='white')


gdf.plot(ax=gax, color='red', alpha = 0.5)

gax.set_xlabel('longitude')
gax.set_ylabel('latitude')
gax.set_title('North America')

gax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
gax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: First step would be to find a geographic plot of the state of California.